# How to add JavaScript to WordPress PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I would like to reference JavaScript files from my root folder in a WordPress PHP file, however when I load the page, the JavaScript is being ignored.  Is there a WordPress restriction on referencing `.js` files? Am I not correctly referencing JavaScript for PHP?

This is what I wrote (which does not work):

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script src="/files/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/files/js/jquery.cycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should be the way to reference a JS-file. If you look at the generated source, does this actually get outputed to source? If you look in the browser devtools, and look at the network traffic as you reload the page, are the JS-files among the files in the list of files that has been loaded?

Comment: have you tried using absolute paths? maybe your site can't find your files.

Comment: You should do it the WordPress way with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: Tutorial to wp_enqueue: http://halfelf.org/2012/jquery-why-u-no-enqueued/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For jQuery I use this technique [Loading The Latest Version of jQuery in WordPress](http://techstudio.co/wordpress/loading-the-latest-version-of-jquery-in-wordpress)

Basically you use `wp_enqueue_script` function in *functions.php*.

For scripts where I want to simply add them in the template files and don't want to bother with `wp_enqueue_script`, I put them in **scripts** folder that was created in the theme folder. I add All custom added .js scripts there.

Then in the template file I use the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=get_template_directory_uri();?>/scripts/markers.js"></script>
```

Comment: If we are using a child theme, do we need a different scripts folder within child theme folder? Or can we add the script to parent theme script folder?

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress has its own method to add js or css files.

```
<?php
function my_scripts_loader() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_loader' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress got a various number of ways to include file, I myself have worked with WordPress in the early days, back then I had to call the path with a WordPress function.

Example: `<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/files/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //add echo`

You might want to var_dump the bloginfo('template_directory') and work your way from there.

Comment: His files are not in template directory as far as I see `/files/js/..`

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 1):

Put  your files folder to your wordpress  theme which you are curently useing   after that just need to

include the path on header.php  file  like

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/files/js/jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

hope this will help  you ....