# How to add custom javascript code in the Wordpress file "single.php"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a problem with adding custom javascript code in the Wordpress file "single.php" I follow these steps, but it didn't work [How to add JavaScript to WordPress PHP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428125/how-to-add-javascript-to-wordpress-php-file)
I dont know if that's happening due to WordPress security purposes or not
 Btw, this is the javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function room_combobox() {
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
text += "<option value=+i+>"+i+"</option>" +"<br>";
}
document.getElementById("combo").innerHTML = "<select name= &#8220; room-adults &#8221; id= &#8220; single-room-adult-selection &#8221; ><option><?php _e( &#8220; No. adults &#8221; , &#8220; nation &#8221; ); ?></option>"+text+"</select>";
}

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: And did you place your script in a file and use `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: So you removed the script tags, and placed the javascript inside a .js file, and used `wp_enqueue_script` ? Where's the code that gets the javascript, as that's what's relevant ?

Comment: @adeneo this code is supposed to create a combo box according to loop, but for some reasons there nothing to show up

Comment: @adeneo yes, I removed the tags

Comment: @adeneo  this is the `wp_enqueue_script` 
 
`if ( is_singular() ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'room_combobox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/room_combobox.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
}`

Comment: @adeneo thnx for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adeneo mentioned, the preferred way to do this is to put the script in it's own file and link to it. Go into the functions.php file for your theme and add the following action:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() {
     if (is_single()) {
         wp_enqueue_script($script_handle, $path_to_script, [$script_dependencies]);
     }
});
```

`$script_handle` can be anything you like. It's a unique key that identifies your script.

`$path_to_script` should point to the location of the js script.

`[$script_dependencies]` should be an array of handles to other js scripts your script depends on. Wordpress has a list of built in libraries like 'jquery'. See here: [Default Wordpress Scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress).

Only the first two parameters are required. You can also add the version and whether or not to embed the script tags on the top or bottom of the page. That's covered in the documentation for `wp_enqueue_script` if you want to know more.

Note also that the issue with your js code, if I'm reading this correctly, is that you're not actually calling the `room_combobox` function. Add the following to your script--It will trigger on document load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    room_combobox()
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help :)
But where can I add this code to call the function? In `room_combobox.js `the javascript file or u mean in `single.php`

Comment: No problem. Add it to room_combobox.js.